# UserControl - DependencyProperty- default values in the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UserControl that works perfectly at run time except the default values. I have used the same UserControl (MaterialUserControl) in two different Tabs in the MainWindow. In one of the Tabs it's default values (RadioButton isChecked values) work fine but not the other?

```
//This is the one which is not setting its default values!
<l:MaterialUserControl x:Name="materialShellUC" stainlessSteelBool="True" Click="shellMaterialBtn_Click" plateBool="True" ENBool="True"/> 
//This one is in another Tab
<l:MaterialUserControl x:Name="materialDishUC" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="materialDish_Click" plateBool="True" stainlessSteelBool="True" ENBool="True"/>

public partial class MaterialUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MaterialUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rootGrid.DataContext = this;
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaterialProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Material", typeof(string),
        typeof(MaterialUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public String Material
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(MaterialProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaterialProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaterialNoProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("MaterialNo", typeof(string),
      typeof(MaterialUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public String MaterialNo
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(MaterialNoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaterialNoProperty, value); }
    }


    public event RoutedEventHandler Click;

    void onButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Click != null)
            this.Click(this, e);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty stainlessSteelBoolProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("strainlessSteelBool", typeof(bool), typeof(MaterialUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public bool stainlessSteelBool
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(stainlessSteelBoolProperty); }
        set { SetValue(stainlessSteelBoolProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty plateBoolProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("plateBool", typeof(bool), typeof(MaterialUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public bool plateBool
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(plateBoolProperty); }
        set { SetValue(plateBoolProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ENBoolProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("ENBool", typeof(bool), typeof(MaterialUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public bool ENBool
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ENBoolProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ENBoolProperty, value); }
    }


}


 //here is the UserControl XAML 
<Grid Background="Pink" x:Name="rootGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Material" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="DarkBlue"/>
        <RadioButton Content="ASME" Grid.Row="1" GroupName="a"/>
        <RadioButton Content="EN" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding ENBool}"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Plate" IsChecked="{Binding plateBool}" Grid.Row="2" GroupName="b"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Tube" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" GroupName="b"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Stainless steel" Grid.Row="3" GroupName="c" IsChecked="{Binding   stainlessSteelBool}"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Carbon Steel" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" GroupName="c"/>
        <Button Content="Material" Grid.Row="4" Click="onButtonClick"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=Material}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding     Path=MaterialNo}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Is it something to do with the DataContext? 
Changes appear in the VS designer but all the RadioButtons value stays null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess this is because the radio buttons in one tab use the same `GroupName` as the radio buttons in another tab, so they are considered part of the same logical group even though they are spread across tabs: when you select a radio button in one tab, you deselect a radio button in the corresponding group of another tab.  Try generating unique group names.

Also, `null` is not a valid default value for a property of type `bool`; either make the default value `false`, or migrate your properties to type `bool?`.

Comment: Is it possible to auto generate the GroupName. I would not like to set each time the GroupNames.

Comment: It's totally fine with Null. I even read that it's better practice to set it to null. The only (main) reason was the GroupName. Since they all where in the same MainWindow, they couldn't have the same GroupNames, hence, causing the confliction. I just don't understand why it worked in the VS design but not in the run time. Thanks Mike, it was quick.

Comment: I wasn't wrong about the default value, but I was wrong about what your code actually does: `new PropertyMetadata(null)` invokes the constructor which takes a `PropertyChangedCallback`, not the constructor which takes a default value.  A default value of `null` *is* invalid for a `bool` property, but that's not what you were actually setting (though it may be what you meant to set).

Comment: I had no intention of setting my for example plateBool = "True". Even if I wanted the compiler would immediately complain. It's just like setting int a = a;

Comment: huh?  I didn't say anything about string values.  All I said was: (1) you cannot specify `null` as a default value for a dependency property of type `bool`; and (2) `new PropertyMetadata(null)` doesn't specify a default value--it specifies a null `PropertyChangedCallback`.  Passing `null` causes a different constructor to be invoked compared to, for example, where you call `new PropertyMetadata("")`.

Comment: And I solve the problem of creating different GroupName DependencyPropertiers by putting each group into a separate Grid in my UserControl. Though, I am not sure whether it's the most elegant way.

Comment: I was talking about the compiler reaction to setting plateBool = "True" is similar to set int a = a; So I don't think anyone could do such an obvious mistake. You are definitely right in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are setting the default values to the dependency properties to be null. Instead of null, set them to false (or true depending on your requirements)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty plateBoolProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("plateBool", typeof(bool), typeof(MaterialUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Comment: Actually, `new PropertyMetadata(null)` binds to the constructor which takes a `PropertyChangedCallback`, not the constructor which takes a default value, so his code is valid, but it probably doesn't do what he intended.  Had he actually specified `null` as the default value for a `bool` dependency property, it would have resulted in a runtime exception.